# How do I fill up this new column using sql >

Tags: sql

I am a bit new to SQL.

I have a table called `hotel_consent_language_code` with the following columns:

```
hotel_consent_key varchar not null,
language_code varchar not null
```

with sample values as shown below:

```
hotel_consent_key                       language_code
-----------------------------------------------------
"consent_key_1"                         "NL"
"00000000-0000-0000-4001-000000000001"  "EN"
"00000000-0000-0000-4001-000000000001"  "NL"
"00000000-0000-0000-4002-000000000002"  "EN"
"00000000-0000-0000-4002-000000000002"  "NL"
```

I am adding another column with name `hotel_uid` to this table.

```
ALTER TABLE hotel_consent_language_code 
    ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS hotel_uid uuid NOT NULL;
```

My aim is to make a composite primary key using the three columns. So I cannot leave the `hotel_uid` column empty.

I need to populate it using another table `hotel_consent` which has columns and data as given below.

```
key                 hotel_uid
------------------------------------------------------------    
"Aconsent_4key_1"   "00000000-0000-0000-4001-000000000001"
"Aconsent_4key_3"   "00000000-0000-0000-4001-000000000001"
"Cconsent_4key_4"   "00000000-0000-0000-4001-000000000001"
"Dconsent_4key_7"   "00000000-0000-0000-4004-000000000001"
"Econsent_4key_5"   "00000000-0000-0000-4001-000000000001"
"Fconsent_4key_2"   "00000000-0000-0000-4001-000000000001"
"consent_key_1"     "00000000-0000-0000-0003-000000000001"
```

The '`key`' column in `hotel_consent` table is the same as '`hotel_consent_key`' column in `hotel_consent_language_code` table.

How do I fill up the `hotel_uid` column in `hotel_consent_language_code` table using the data from `hotel_consent`table ?

Can I actually accomplish this without mismatching any data in the `hotel_consent_language_code` table ?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: I am using Postgres SQL.